# How to remember for-loops iterating variable inside function and if-statements in batch-file?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I want to automate the execution of several bdf-files in a folder. But, I can only have one instance of my application running at the time (due to my license for the applicetion).

I want my code to do like below:

FOR ALL *.bdf files in folder DO THIS:
CHECK IF application is running
IF running, START index.bdf (with default application)
IF NOT running, WAIT a little, then go to "CHECK IF" again
Continue For-loop

My code look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE AutorunNastran
FOR %%f IN (*.bdf) DO (
    :loopbody
        tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq nastran.exe" | find /i "nastran.exe" >nul && (
        echo Nastran is running
        TIMEOUT 5
        goto loopbody
        ) || (
        echo Nastran is not running, a new bdf-file will be executed
        START %%f
        )
)
PAUSE
```

The first .bdf file will be executed, but it seems that my variable index.bdf=%%f is forgotten the second and third time the program is running through i-statements.

I'm new to batch-files, but I've tried to find answer on google, and think maybe I need to have this command "`Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`", but it has'nt worked for me so far.
Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: cannot work in this way.`GOTO` breaks the for loop context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing a `goto` inside a loop cancels the loop. Try with

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "app=nastran.exe"

    for %%a in (*.bdf) do (
        cmd /q /c"(for /l %%z in (0) do (tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %app%" | find /i "%app%" && timeout 5 || exit /b)) >nul 2>&1"
        start "" "%%~a"
    )
```

Here the loop is moved to a separate `cmd` instance that will keep an infinite loop until the app is not found in `tasklist`

Comment: Thanks alot! Your code works perfectly, and now all thats left for me, is to go through it step by step to actually understand it. And I'm going to do that now :-)